# javascript - how to fade in div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

I want to fade in a div class when a click action is made. But it's not working.

[image]

the picture above is produced by function gotData.

```
 function gotData(data) { 

var jobs = data.val();
var keys = Object.keys(jobs);

var container = document.getElementById('Jobcontainer'); 
var container2 = document.getElementById('jobpackage'); 


for (var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++) {
var k = keys[i];
var newCard = `

 <li class="pos-card" id="Jobcontainer">
    <div class="content"> 
      <div class="title">`+jobs[k].JobTitle+`</div>
      <div class="date">April 21</div>
      <div class="refer">Refer</div>
    </div>
  <ul class="desc"> 
    <li>`+ jobs[k].JobSummary + `</li>
  </ul>
</li>`;

container.innerHTML += newCard;

}
}
```

in the same file html tag I have this html code

```
<div class="return">Return to listings   </div>
<div class="container refer-card">
<div class="modal confirmed"><span class="close-modal"></span>
<h2>Thank you!</h2>
<p><span id="refer_name" class="focus"></span> has been submitted for   the <span id="refer_pos" class="focus"></span> position.</p>
</div>
<div class="sign-up card">
 <div class="card__header"> 
  <h1>Employee Referral</h1>
  <div class="description">For more information, please consult the   <a href="#">employee handbook</a>.</div>
 </div>
 <div class="card__content">
  <form class="referral" method="post">
    <div class="field line">
      <input class="req" maxlength="240" type="text" name="name" value="" required="required" id="name"/>
      <label class="placeholder" for="name">Full Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field line">
      <input class="req" maxlength="240" type="email" name="email" value="" required="required" id="email"/>
      <label class="placeholder" for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field line inline">
      <input class="req" maxlength="240" type="text" name="position" value="" required="required" id="position"/>
      <label class="placeholder" for="position">Position</label>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="field inline right"><span class="dropdown-wrapper">
        <select class="empty" name="department" id="choice">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Department</option>
          <option value="1">Development</option>
          <option value="2">Sales</option>
          <option value="3">QA</option>
          <option value="4">Design</option>
          <option value="5">HR</option>
          <option value="6">Research  </option>
        </select></span></div> -->
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" id="btn"/>
    </div><a class="reset" href="#">Reset </a>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I am attempting to use the JS function below to fade in refer-card in the html tag when "refer" in picture above is clicked but for some unknown reasons nothing is happening and no error is displayed. Can you help figure out what I'm doing wrong or missing?

```
$('.refer').click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
$('.positions').addClass('fadeOut');
$('.refer-card').addClass('show');
$('.return').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Comment: What CSS do you have in place?  I've set up a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmdgmv) to test, but I don't have sample jobs or the CSS to hide the return link for instance.

Comment: you might not have defined query 

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Also ensure you have written the statements in $(document).ready()

Comment: @TejPatil I defined the query. what do you mean by having the statement written in $(document).ready()

Comment: There might be possibility that your script executes before the .refer element is rendered.  Writing your code in 
$(document).ready(function(){....}) will ensure the script is executed after the document is ready with html
 - https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

Try this codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmdgmv)

Perhaps you have not defined jQuery, as it seems to work with a sample job block I put in place, and the basic CSS to hide the element you are trying to fade in.  Also, bear in mind that if you've hidden it with '!important' in your CSS then the fade in will not work.

I added a `console.log('clicked');` to your click handler verify that the block is executing.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you've called the [gotData] method that would append the html tag with the 'refer' class in play thus by that time, (refer) class didnt register or bind the [click] event handler after loading the DOM

In this case, you need to attach / bind them beforehand using (on) or (delegate) method (If you want to apply this in jQuery)

Using (on) method:

```
$('.refer').on('click', function(event) {
     $('.positions').addClass('fadeOut');
      // rest of code
 });
```

Using (delegate) method:

```
$(document).delegate('.refer', 'click', function(event) {
    $('.positions').addClass('fadeOut');
    // rest of code
 });
```

Hope this helps for your case.

Comment: I tried both methods but no success. thanks for the help though

Comment: @Ola Did you've checked the (console) window to see if theres an error in your JS?

Comment: yes i checked but error displayed. code used is below                                           $('.refer').on('click', function(event) {
     $('.positions').addClass('fadeOut');
   $('.refer-card').addClass('show');
   $('.return').fadeIn('fast');

 });

Comment: What message did you get on your console?

Comment: Try to check in your [Network] Tab on [console] window to see if the script where you've called those events / method (getData) was loaded properly.

<script src="js/sample.js">